# should output to file go into ViewModel or Model?

Tags: c#, mvvm

When trying to fit my program into the MVVM model, I was wondering where classes and other pieces of the program that produce printed (eg. to file) output should go.
Into the V, the M or the VM?

Also: I have a numeric formatting routine that is used for the file output as well as for the XAML output. Where should that routine go? Or more general: how would I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a button click executes the print action:

You need to have a `command` in the `viewmodel` that is bound to the `button`. The `command implementation` in the `viewmodel` should pass the `model` to an `extra object` (e.g. ModelFileSaver), which is responsible for saving the model to a file.

Not every piece of logic has to be in the model or viewmodel, it is often necessary to create additional classes that solve a particular problem and use these classes in the viewmodels.

In my opinion models should only contain methods that change the model itself, but not do something outside the boundaries of the model (like saving to a file).